# Console gets data but API call doesn't when using same method

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, api

I'm in the middle of creating a multi-tier application which includes the following layers

**API**

**Business**

**DAL**

-

**Entities**

All Layers have access to the Entities and also access to the layer that is beneath them in the list.

I also have a Console project.

My problem is that I make a call to the Business layer to get all data from a table, it works fine and retrieves two rows. However, I used the same method inside my API layer and it returns no rows - it also throws no errors and has left me stranded.

These are the classes/methods:

**API:**

```
public class CompaniesController : ApiController
{
    CompaniesService _companiesService = new CompaniesService();

    public IEnumerable<Company> GetAllCompanies()
    {
        return _companiesService.GetAllCompanies();
    }
}
```

**Business:**

```
public class CompaniesService
{
    public List<Company> GetAllCompanies()
    {
        var companyRepository = new CompanyRepository();

        return companyRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

**DAL:**

```
public class CompanyRepository
{
    public List<Company> GetAll()
    {
        //create DBContext object
        using (var context = new dbEntities())
        {
            var data = context.Company.ToList();

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
[Table("Companies")]
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public string Exchange { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework 6 on Visual Studio 2013 and using a MySQL Database. Each layer is inside of a different project - just in case this is a reference based problem.

Comment: have you checked the difference in connection strings?  obviously they (projects) are using different configs.

Comment: You are correct, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple fix, I simply didn't have the correct connection string inside of the API Project.